# Rails 5.2 - Detecting type of content within a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Allowing users to upload a CSV, and then I output a sample of the CSV for them to validate. With this I want to include the 'guesstimated' field type next to it (String, Number, etc - high-level).

Currently I am using:

**View**

```
<p>
  <strong>Spec Sheet SAMPLE (Live Data):</strong>
    <%#= image_tag url_for(@post.cover_photo) %>
    <% preview_data = CSV.foreach(ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, @post.cover_photo.blob.key)).take(10) %>
    <table style="width:50%">
      <tr>
        <% preview_data[0].each do |header| %>
          <th><%= header %> </th>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
          <% preview_data.drop(1).each do |row| %>
            <tr>
              <% row.each do |info| %>
                <td><%= info %> <%= type_sense(info) %></td>
              <% end %>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
    </table>
</p>
```

**Controller**

```
def type_sense(content)
  if content.is_a? Integer
    return 'Number' 
  elsif content.is_a? String
    return 'Text'
  end
end

helper_method :type_sense
```

Which I get - technically everything in the arrays being made via the CSV are strings.

I notice as soon as the file is uploaded everything is double quoted, which I am assuming turns it into a string, despite it being rendered as as it's original value.

**Note** I do understand that it will incorrectly flag some things as others, but for this test case I am just trying to get it to register 9 digits as an 'Integer' and letters as 'text'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions:

```
def type_sense(content)
  case content
  when /\A\d+\z/ then 'Number' #matches a string with only digits in it 
  else 'Text' #if it's not a number, then it's text, I guess you want to count "some123thing" as text
  end
end
```

If you only want to count letters (and spaces?) as "Text" then use

```
when /\A\d+\z/ then 'Number' #matches a string with only digits in it 
when /\A[a-zA-Z\s]+\z/ then 'Text'
else 'Unknown'
```

You can play with different regular expressions if you need different contents (like a date, or a phone number, or anything that has some pattern)

Comment: RegEx it is - Thanks. Wasn't sure if there was a helper to help with this.